# Excel VBA: Returning the cell value of calculated result

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA function:

```
Function IndexOfColor(InRange As Range, ColorIndex As Long) As Excel.Range
Dim R As Range

Application.Volatile True
If IsValidColorIndex(ColorIndex) = False Then
    IndexOfColor = 0
    Exit Function
End If

For Each R In InRange.Cells
    If R.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex Then
        IndexOfColor = R
        Exit Function
    End If
Next R

IndexOfColor = 0
End Function
```

In my excel sheet, I call this:

```
=IndexOfColor(D15:M24,37)
```

And always get `"#VALUE"`.  I've debugged the function, right until the end, and no problems there.  While this should just return 1 result (I'm looking at the range, and there is only one colored cell), I've also tried making this an array result (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER).

Suggestions?

Comment: What is CI? Shouldn't it be `ColorIndex`?

Comment: `While this should just return 1 result` Also what is `1` How did you arrive at that? The function is supposed to return a range `) As Excel.Range` ? Perhaps if you can exactly explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I see your function defined with two parameters, `InRange` and `ColorIndex`, but I see you calling the function with 3 parameters `D15:M24`,`37` and `0`

Comment: Sorry guys, tried to simplify the code as much as possible to highlight the problem, but incorrectly edited.  Now, it is edited to a compiled state with only 2 params.

Comment: Is `1` that is expected the value of the cell?

Comment: @siddharth I also edited the explaination, but one more time... I am doing just a visual check in the range in question, and I see there is just one colored cell. Thanks.

Comment: Oh so you are trying to find the number of say "Red" color cells in a range?

Comment: @siddharth I am expecting the same value of the cell in the range, thus if the colored cell has the value "42", I excpect the cell with the formula to also show "42".  Thanks

Comment: Oh in that case change `As Excel.Range` to `As Long` or `As Variant` in case the cell has text values. Else you will have to do proper error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? If the cells will not have decimals then you can replace `Variant` with `Long`

```
Function IndexOfColor(InRange As Range, ColorIndex As Long) As Variant
    Dim R As Range

    IndexOfColor = 0

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.Volatile True

    If Not IsValidColorIndex(ColorIndex) = False Then
        For Each R In InRange.Cells
            If R.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex Then
                IndexOfColor = R.Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next R
    End If
Whoa:
End Function
```

Comment: "As Long" was what I was looking for.  Actually, I had this before, but was blinded by the wrong formatting, so thought the number was a pointer of some sort.